# file quantity limit in a directory on a linux file server and why?

Tags: parsing, file-structure, file-systems

What is a good limit to use on the quantity of files in a directory, and why?

EDIT:
Why shouldn't someone create a system that puts hundreds of thousands of files in the same directory?

**Why I ask:**

Someone set up a system that dumps files in a folder with a human readable date-time.

My task it to create a system that gets the files for a select time period.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem but the folder has 500,000 files in it and is growing and my system is expected to get them in real time.

Parsing 500,000 files takes too long, so I think it is the responsibility of the person who built the system that inputs the files on the FTP server to create a directory structure such as having a sub folder for each day.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Comment: If you want to sort the files into directories based on their date, that could probably be done with a relatively simple script. If you actually want to limit the number of objects in a directory, that would probably need to be done as an OS kernel, or some kind of add-on for your filesystem. Probably a lot more work to do that than to write a sorting script.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I agree with the sorting/subdir script but I am trying to give business reasons why it is needed

Comment: @Quinma: Try actually parsing that many files just to see how long it takes. If it really takes an unacceptably long amount of time, then you probably have a very good case to get permission to run a sorting script.

Comment: What kind of application are you developing?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch a web application to expose files from the FTP server for a selected period of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the actual system (operating system, computer hardware, file system). Some [old Linux] file systems behaved badly (linear access time w.r.t. to number of directory entries). So it is generally preferable to have small sized directories of a few thousand entries at most (and this also makes the shell more happy: you might want to `ls` the directory). It is usually inefficient to have millions of very small files (e.g. a hundred bytes each), because often each file uses at least one file-system block.

So I would suggest having files like `dir001/file001.txt` .... `dir123/file345.txt` ....

Consider also using some other way of storing data: some indexed data file like [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/), a [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or [PostGresql](http://postgresql.org/) or [MongoDb](http://mongodb.org/) database, etc. And you might even mix the approach: use Sqlite for some meta-data about your files, and keep them in many directories. You might also have a seggregative approach: handle differently small contents and bigger ones (put the small contents in Sqlite or GDBM, and the large contents in files).

Answer (score 1):

Stock answer: "It depends".

Trying to do anything of any size or complexity using the file system as a "database" is going to be tricky and trying to do it "in real time" is going to be downright difficult.
The problem is that you tend to have *lots* of files, which means that you have to operate on "a" file many, many times.  Doing "something" once takes an amount of time; doing that "something" many times takes *many times* longer; it doesn't scale well.

That said, you can offset this overhead this by organising your data sensibly. 
You say you're working with date ranges, so arrange your files into a directory structure that supports this, an obvious choice might be this:

```
root/
  2014/
    01/ 
      01/
        2014-01-01-00-00-00.dat 
        2014-01-01-00-00-01.dat 
      02/
        2014-01-02-00-00-00.dat 
        2014-01-02-00-00-01.dat
```

Now, retrieving a days'-worth of files is relatively straight-forward (and, therefore, quick).

Of course, depending on what you're doing, loading the whole thing into a *database* might be a better solution ...   YMMV